# CakePHP 2.2 saveAll multiple models validation

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I'm trying to validate multiple models on saveAll. The validations in the first model are being triggered but when it comes to the related model, nothing seems to be happening. I even tried to check if the beforeValidate() and beforeSave() methods are being called by putting an exit; in them but the code continues to execute as normal.

ContactDetails Model:

```
<?php
class ContactDetails extends ContactAppModel {  
    public $actsAs = array("MapValidate");
    public $hasMany = array(
        'ProjectLocation' => array(
            'className'     => 'ProjectLocation',
            'foreignKey'    => 'project_id'
        )
    );

    public $validate = array(
        'name' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Contact name is required'
            )
        ),
        'address1' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Contact address 1 is required'
            )
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Contact email is required'
            ),
            'email' => array(
                'rule' => array('email'),
                'message' => 'Contact email format is not valid'
            )
        )
    );
}
```

ProjectLocation Model:

```
<?php
class ProjectLocation extends ContactAppModel {
    public $actsAs = array("MapValidate");
    public $belongsTo = array(
        "ContactDetails" => array(
            "className" => "ContactDetails",
            "foreignKey" => "project_id"
        );
    );

    public $validate = array(
        'lat' => array(
           'checkLocation' => array(
                'rule'    => array('checkMap', 'lat'),
                'message' => 'One or more positions on the map are invalid.'
            )
        )
    );  
}
```

This is the $this->request->data that I'm trying to save:

```
Array
(
    [ContactDetails] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => PreeoStudios
            [address1] => 4, Stivala Street
            [address2] => Mosta, MST 3205
            [address3] => Malta
            [telephone] => 34562737
            [email] => info@preeostudios.com
            [fax] => N/A
            [skype] => N/A
        )

    [ProjectLocation] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [lat] => 35.886277456343024
                    [lon] => 14.428907312499973
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [lat] => 35.886277456343024
                    [lon] => 14.528907312499973
                )

        )

)
```

The saveAll call:

```
$this->ContactDetails->saveAll($this->request->data, array('validate' => 'first'))
```

*EDIT*

I also tried to remove the validation rules from the associated model and put an exit in the beforeSave function... the code just keeps executing

```
<?php
class ProjectLocation extends ContactAppModel {
    public $actsAs = array("MapValidate");
    public $belongsTo = array(
        "ContactDetails" => array(
            "className" => "ContactDetails",
            "foreignKey" => "project_id"
        );
    );

    public function beforeSave(){
        exit;
    }

    public $validate = array(

    );  
}
```

Comment: Can you also post the code for the `checkMap` validation method you defined? You could also try to use `saveAssociated()` just for a test.
Also why are you passing the string "lat" to the validation?

Comment: I would try to save a row for ProjectLocation and see if it gets validated. Like Borislav Sabev said, you don't need to pass the field name to the custom validation rule. It's a bit weird, but the field name is passed in the first param by default, followed by other arguments specified after the validation function name.

Comment: I tried to do what you told me but still no sucess :/ I updated the question with some changes I tried.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the option deep:

```
$this->ContactDetails->saveAll($this->request->data, array('validate' => 'first', 'deep' => true))
```

From: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array

Answer (score 1):

You can get validation result for multiply models using saveAll:

```
$validate = $this->Model->saveAll($this->request->data, array('validate' => 'only'));
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer?